# SelectSingleNode returns the wrong Node instance value

Tags: c#, xml

I am parsing some XML. I am iterating over 2 `Pit` nodes and trying to find out their `x` node value.

**My problem:** When I inspect each `Pit` nodes `x` value its always says value is `8`, when the second nodes `x` value is actually `1`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
XmlNodeList xNodes = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ns:pits", nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode pit in xNodes) {
    XmlNode x = pit.SelectSingleNode("//ns:x", nsmgr);
    MessageBox.Show(x.InnerText, "");  // Always prints "8", when 1 should be "8", another "1"
}
```

The data I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml12d>
    <pit>
      <x>8.89268569</x>
      <y>1.26122586</y>
      <z>1.62414621</z>
    </pit>
    <pit>
      <x>1.09268598</x>
      <y>7.24091243</y>
      <z>8.20896044</z>
    </pit>
</xml12d>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XPath `//` is an [abbreviated syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) to select any descendant from the document root. `//ns:x` will select every `ns:x` in the document -- it isn't scoped to its parent node as a root -- so using it with `SelectSingleNode` will always select the first `ns:x` in the document.

If you change the XPath to simply `ns:x`, which will select only *child* `ns:x`, it should work.

You can actually get rid of the second XPath call by modifying the first to select `//ns:pits/ns:x[1]`, which will select the first `ns:x` child of every `ns:pits` in the document.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
XmlNode x = pit.SelectSingleNode(".//ns:x", nsmgr);
```

Notice the dot (`.`) before `//ns:x`